# In GCP, how to handle KMSes that are parts of test deployments?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-kms

In my GCP deployment, I use its own KMS that is created on the fly. The deployment is created hundred times a day (for tests). After a test is finished, deployment is terminated and removed. So far so good. The only problem is that after the deletion, created KMS, or better to say its remnants stay forever (because, as we all perfectly know, the KMS keys can't be deleted).

My tests test the deployment, i.e. they need to make a new deployment for each run, and because the KMS is supposed to be a part of the deployment (on the customer side), it can't be eliminated from the tested deployment.

How am I supposed to solve this task?

Cross-posted to:

- https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/comments/nv2uav/how_to_handle_kmses_that_are_parts_of_test/
- https://groups.google.com/g/google-cloud-dev/c/WwHCmqIqNKU

Comment: You can't delete KMS keys. You can use UUIDs or other random IDs for the key names, or create new projects.

Comment: You can delete all the key versions, you will not be billed for key rings or keys with no active key versions. That said, given the fact that you'll have thousands of old keys and key rings from previous runs, I suggest deleting the project and creating a new one -- if not on each run, at least occasionally.

Comment: @sethvargo: Sure, I can't delete the KMS keys. That's why I asked this question

Comment: @TimDierks: probably it is the only working solution; I wonder how this problem is solved usually, because it is quite typical, in my opinion

Comment: There are pretty strict quotas on creating new projects within a 30d period though, so check your quotas to be certain. For CI jobs, I usually generate a UUID for key names.

Comment: @sethvargo: but you use an external KMS, that's not created as a part of your deployment? Right?

Comment: I'll ask the KMS team to track a feature request to deal with this situation better. I agree that we don't support it well now. Thanks for using GCP and KMS!

Comment: I spoke with the team and we've tested KMS with up to 50 million keys in a single project, so I think there's no need to delete projects to clean out old keyrings and keys. However, you do need to track and delete key versions to avoid being billed for them. I'm going to submit an answer around this guidance, and we've taken a feature request to provide more detailed documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice for this right now is to:

- Have a test project for these keys.
- On every run, create a key ring with a random name (e.g. use a UUID).
- Create a key within that key ring (you can use a constant name or another UUID).
- After your tests complete, destroy the key material for that key.

This project will accumulate a large number of empty key rings and keys, which you will not be charged for. However, this should not be a practical problem; we have tested KMS with up to 50 million keys in a project without running into limits. However, the UI is not well-suited to managing with these many key rings, so you will need to rely on the API for any operations.

Thanks for using GCP and KMS!

Comment: This approach seems to have a problem though: as soon as you create a key with the deploy manager, you can't delete the deployment anymore (because the key blocks the whole deployment). You can use `--delete-policy abandon`, but that would mean that all resources are abandonned, not only the keys which is also a no go. Maybe there is some other trick? Something like delete policy per resource?